# prove that $a_n$ is convergent if $\limsup a_n \cdot \limsup \frac1{a_n} = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

$a_n$ is a positive series, and I know that $\limsup a_n \cdot \limsup \frac1{a_n} = 1$.

Prove that $a_n$ is convergent.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I know that the multiplication is 1. But I don't know how to prove it..

Comment: This question is based on similar idea: [Show that $\limsup \frac1{x_n}\cdot \limsup x_n\geq 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33905/show-that-limsup-frac1x-n-cdot-limsup-x-n-geq-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show that $$\limsup\frac1{a_n}=\frac1{\liminf a_n},$$
(for any sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n>0$)?

Once you prove this, the equality you are given simply says that $\limsup a_n=\liminf a_n$.

You can find this also in the book
*Wieslawa J. Kaczor, Maria T. Nowak: Problems in mathematical analysis: Volume 1; Real Numbers, Sequences and Series* as Problems 2.4.22 and 2.4.23. The problems are given on [p.45](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA45) and solved on [p.203-204](http://books.google.com/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&pg=PA203).

Comment: Maybe I asked the original question wrong, I got to this part, but my problem is proving it..

Comment: I think I misread the original post, @Lee